# net core file uploading vis postman loading indefinitely

Tags: .net-core, file-upload, postman

```
    [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile() 
    {

        var formCollection = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
        var file = formCollection.Files.First();

        //TODO: Implement the logic

        return Ok();

    }
```

Above is the Backend code. I am trying to upload a file via postman but the request is not hitting the action and getting no errors and loading forever.

I am working with .NET 5

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Body to form-data, in Postman
[image]

From there, **set the KEY as File**, and **select a file for the VALUE** field.